# ffmpeg DTS output issue creates double length files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to concatenate mp4 files with the following command line.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -y -f concat -copytb 1 -safe 0 -i .\list.txt -c:a copy -c copy $outputFileName
```

I get a number of errors on these files.

```
Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filterx
```

And more imporantly a lot of these errors.

```
[mp4 @ 0000000002574720] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1628167, current: 1603584; changing to 1628168. This may result
in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0000000002574720] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1628168, current: 1604096; changing to 1628169. This may result
in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0000000002574720] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1628169, current: 1604608; changing to 1628170. This may result
in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0000000002574720] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1628170, current: 1605120; changing to 1628171. This may result
in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

The individual files seem to play just fine, and the final output file plays, but has a length exactly double that of the input files.

In other words when I get to the "end" of the video, the player reports that the video still has half way to go.

i am happy to re-encode the audio if necessary to correct this problem.
any suggestions on how to correct it are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Remove copytb. The bitstream filter msg doesn't signal an error. The DTS warnings can be ignored if the video/audio plays fine.

Comment: I have tried without copytb, same result.
it really is weird. I can play the full video through, the length is just weirdly double.

Comment: We can isolate whether it's the audio or video streams cuasing it. Run the concat twice, once with `-vn` and then with `-an`.

Comment: if have tried once with
`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -an -y -f concat -copytb 1 -safe 0 -i .\list.txt -c:a copy -c copy $outputFileName
`
and once with
`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -vn -y -f concat -copytb 1 -safe 0 -i .\list.txt -c:a copy -c copy $outputFileName`

The output is the same, with the file being double length, just on the timings.

Comment: `vn/an` have to go after `-i list.txt`